# 年齢分布テーブルを求めるSQL

Tags: sql

下記のテーブルA,テーブルBから、年齢の分布テーブルを求めるSQLが知りたいです。

テーブルA：ユーザIDと年齢のテーブル

ユーザID、年齢
1,20
2,21
3,26
4,68
5,34
6,16
...

テーブルB：年齢の区分テーブル

区分ID、年齢下限、年齢上限
1,0,10
2,11,20
3,21,30
4,31,40
5,41,50
6,51,60
7,61,70
8,71,120
..

欲しい年齢区分テーブルは以下を想定しております。

欲しいテーブル：各年齢区分にユーザが何人いるかのテーブル

区分ID,ユーザ人数,年齢範囲
1,100,0-10
2,20,11-20
3,41,21-30
5,77,31-40
....

CASEやSUM,JOINを使用して出来るのではないかと思うのですが...
ご教授お願いいたします。

Comment: ありがとうございます。できました。

Comment: この例の場合は使えませんが、均等分布のヒストグラムなら`width_bucket`が使えます。それならJOINの必要もありません。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sa-yさんの回答とほぼ同じですが

```
SELECT
  区分ID,
  COUNT(ユーザID) AS ユーザ人数,
  CONCAT(MIN(年齢下限), '-', MIN(年齢上限)) AS 年齢範囲
FROM テーブルB
LEFT OUTER JOIN テーブルA ON 年齢 BETWEEN 年齢下限 AND 年齢上限
GROUP BY 区分ID;
```

`LEFT OUTER JOIN`を使用すると0人の区分も得られ、ここを`INNER JOIN`に変更すると0人の区分が省かれます。支障ないと思いますが`ユーザID`が`NULL`でないことを前提に集計してます。

Comment: COUNT(ユーザID) がポイントですね。これが一番スマートですかねー。

Answer (score 2):

このテーブル構成だとテーブルBのレコード数は多くて数十個かと思います。
その前提で回答しますと、以下のように素直に相関サブクエリ記述して問題なく動作するかと思われます。

```
INSERT INTO C (age_class_id, user_count, age_range)
SELECT
        B.age_class_id AS age_class_id
,       (
                SELECT
                        COUNT(*) AS user_count
                FROM
                        A
                WHERE
                        B.min_age <= A.age AND A.age <= B.max_age
        ) AS class_user_count
,
        (B.min_age || '-' || B.max_age) AS age_range 
FROM B
```

追記)
もしユーザが０人の年齢区分のレコードを作成しなくてよいのであれば、以下のように INNER JOIN する方法になるかと思います。

```
INSERT INTO C (age_class_id, user_count, age_range)
SELECT
        B.age_class_id AS age_class_id
,       COUNT(*) AS class_user_count
,       (B.min_age || '-' || B.max_age) AS age_range
FROM B
INNER JOIN A
        ON A.age BETWEEN B.min_age  AND B.max_age
GROUP BY
        B.age_class_id
```

※ SQLite で確認したSQLですのでお使いのデータベースエンジンに合わせて書き換えてください。

Answer (score -3):

```sql
select *
from テーブルA a
    join テーブルB b
        on a.年齢 between b.年齢下限 and b.年齢上限
```